# DisplayAll button not working in RWD table

Tags: javascript, html, css, responsive-design, grocery-crud

In my Application,I am showing records using `RWD table`.I pick from [this](http://gergeo.se/RWD-Table-Patterns/#demo) link. After I templating table with records.Everything is working except `DisplayAll` button.

After I template `table`.I ran the following code then only `DisplayAll and Display` elements are coming.

```
  $('.table-responsive').responsiveTable({"addFocusBtn":false});
```

`Display` element is working fine but `DisplayAll` not working.

I check their source code,but I didn't find the solution.

can anyone help me.I stuck here.